# Rstudio - Error in user-created function - Object not found

Tags: r, function

First thing's first; my skills in R are somewhat lacking, so there is a chance I may be using something incorrectly in the following. If I go wrong somewhere, please let me know.

I've been having a problem in Rstudio where I try to create 2 functions for formulae, then use nls() to create a model using those, with which I will make a plot. When I try to run the line for creating it, I get an error message saying an object is missing. It is always the last object in the function of the first "formula", in this case, 'p'.

I'll provide my code here then explain what I am trying to do for a little context;

```
DATA <- read.csv(file.choose(), as.is=T)

formula <- function(m, h, g, p){(2*m)/(m+(sqrt(m^2+1)))*p*g*(h^2/2)}
formula.2 <- function(P, V, g){P*V*g}

m = 0.85
p = 766.42
g = 9.81
P = 0.962
h = DATA$lithothick
V = DATA$Vol

fit.1 <- nls(formula (P, V, g) ~ formula(m, h, g, p), data = DATA)
```

If I run it how it is shown, I get the error;

```
Error in (2 * m)/(m + (sqrt(m^2 + 1))) * p : 'p' is missing
```

However it will show h if I rearrange the objects in the formula to (m,g,p,h)

```
Error in h^2 : 'h' is missing
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is this; I have a .csv file with 3 thicknesses (0.002, 0.004, 0.006 meters) and 3 volumes (10, 25, 50 milliliters). I am trying to see how the rates of strength and buoyancy increase (in relation to each other) as the thickness and volume for each object (respectively) increases. I was hoping to come out with a graph showing the upward trend for each property (strength and buoyancy), as I believe them to be unequal (one exponential the other linear). I hope that isn't more confusing than clarifying, but any pointers would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You don't have a problem in RStudio. You have a problem with R and not with the IDE.

Comment: Did you mean to use `formula.2(P, V, g)`? R is complaining that you are passing only three parameters to a four-parameter function.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, well I have to use both for what I'm trying to get.

Comment: Well, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. `nls` is used to fit parameters, but you seem to know all parameters.

Comment: Sorry about that, what I did was create predictions based off that model, 'melt' that dataset with the "reshape" package, and from there plot it using "ggplot". I was only able to complete this in little tests earlier, but they aren't useful in this instance so I now need to make this one work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload functions this way in R, what you can do is provide optional arguments (which is a kind of overload) with syntax `function(mandatory, optionnal="")`

For what you are trying to do, you have to use `formula.2` if you want to use the 3-arguments formula.

A workaround could be to use one function with one optionnal argument and check if this argument has been used. Something like :

```
formula = function(m, h, g, p="") {
  if (is.numeric(p)) {
    (2*m)/(m+(sqrt(m^2+1)))*p*g*(h^2/2)
  } else {
   m*h*g
  }
}
```

This is ugly and a very bad way to do it (your variables do not really mean the same thing from one call to the other) but it works.

Comment: Thanks for that!
How do you mean use `function.2`? I have to use both equations to get the plot I'm after. If I see it right, your code means it will use either one or the other?

Comment: I meant `formula.2`, misprint. And yes, this function will use the long formula if your provide 4 arguments and the short one otherwise.

Comment: Alright, sure. Yeah I meant to type `formula.2`, my bad. 
As to the fitting of the model, is the code still
    `fit.1 <- nls(formula (P, V, g) ~ formula(m, p, g, h), data = DATA)`

I tried this and got the following error;

    `Error in getInitial.default(func, data, mCall =      as.list(match.call(func,  : 
  no 'getInitial' method found for "function" objects
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: This is another problem, linked to how you are using nls. All the arguments in the formula (ie in your example `m, p, g, P, H and V`) must be vectors. Then, you need some values to fit (ie not defined), and here you are only providing defined variables. You have to understand how `formulas` in R work to get what you want.

Comment: So I've tried this, but you said the values can't just be defined so I'm not sure this is quite what you meant, but here it is:
`h.vector <- seq(from = 0.002, to = 0.006, by = 0.001)
V.vector <- seq(from = 10, to = 50, by = 10)

DATA2 <- data.frame(h=h.vector, V=V.vector, m= 0.85, p= 766.42, g= 9.81, P= 0.962)`

I'm using the the formula you gave along with the short one from my original code, as well as the "fit.1" line. This gives me the same error message minus the additional warning above (so it's just the "no 'getInitial' method"). 
Thanks for the help so far, but where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `nls` is used to fit the parameters of a formula to data. It means is uses several vectors of data and tries to adjust some parameter. Let's take the simple formula `y ~ A * x` : `x` and `y` are *vectors or lists* and `A` is an _undefined variable_ (you can make sure of that with `rm(A)` before calling the function). In your example, all your variables exist, and some are not *vectors* (this is why you get the `getInitial` error). If you do not want to fit `g` for example, you have to use `rep(g, length(V))` in your data.

Comment: In the end, your formula is `existing_vector_1 ~ existing_vector_2` so `nls` has nothing to do. You must use _undefined variable_ and only in the second term of the formula, e.g. `rm(A); nls(y ~ A * x)` would adjust `A` to minimise the residual for this formula. Overall, I strongly recommend you look into a book on R formula (and fitting function such as `nls` and `glm`), because they are the basics if you want to do fitting in R.

Comment: Btw, given the name of your variables, I assume this is physics. Your two functions do not return the same unit, one in Newtons and the other Newtons/meters. So I think you want to fit a distance, your formula should then be `formula (P, V, g) ~ d * formula(m, h, g, p)` where you would fit `d`.